# Insert Time line card using Mirror API, which has bundle inside bundle?

Tags: c#, .net, google-mirror-api, google-glass

How to Insert Time line card using In C#.Net Mirror API, which has bundle inside bundle?

In below code what I am doing is create a single bundle.
What I want is item1 and item2 to be different bundles. Is is possible?
Is there a solution?

```
           TimelineItem item = new TimelineItem()
            {
                Text = controller.Request.Form.Get("message"),
                BundleId = "112",
                IsBundleCover=true,
                Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" }
            };

            TimelineItem item1 = new TimelineItem()
            {
                Text = "Amalan",
                BundleId = "112",
                Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" }
            };

            TimelineItem item2 = new TimelineItem()
            {
                Text = "Sanath",
                BundleId = "112",
                Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" }
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested bundles aren't currently supported in the Mirror API, there's an issue you can star to get updates on the progress in this area: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=167

Depending on your use case, you can also try to work around this by using HTML cards with paging for the inside bundles, but this will only work if the cards in the bundle all have the same Menu Items.

So instead of creating a bundle of several cards you would create one card where you put all the contents of all cards as HTML, and then either let it `auto-paginate` or explicitely define the content of the separate cards. See https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#paginating for details and examples.

You can then add each of these paginated HTML cards to your bundle.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, its a good alternative. But is not paginating deprecated?

Comment: The old way to paginate using "htmlPages" is deprecated, the new way in the documentation link in my answer is working.