# How to add Timeline item bundle inside another bundle in google glass

Tags: google-mirror-api, mirror, google-glass

We have to add a Timeline item bundle inside another bundle.

Like this flow

----Main bundle

```
|
-----Sub bundle
     |
     ----Timeline item
     |
     ----Timeline item
-----Sub bundle
     |
     ----Timeline item
     |
     ----Timeline item
-----Sub bundle
     |
     ----Timeline item
     |
     ----Timeline item
```

can any body help us on this

Comment: See my answer on this similar question that coincidentally came a few minutes before yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044167/insert-time-line-card-using-mirror-api-which-has-bundle-inside-bundle

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it is not the way I need.

Answer (score 1):

The Mirror API only allows going one level in from the main timeline as of XE9 using either [HTML pagination](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#paginating) or [bundles](https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline#bundling_cards).

I can see a few places where it would be handy and hopefully they'll offer a neat implementation in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not enough for my requirements. I use native application development for my application.

Comment: You've tagged this as "google-mirror-api." Are you rather sideloading a native APK onto Glass?

Comment: My question was about Timeline so it related to google-mirror-api. Since I couldn't do it using Mirror API I use Native application.